# What is Android App Bundle (.aab) file MIME type?

Tags: android-studio, mime-types, android-app-bundle

Wanted to know Android App Bundle (.aab) MIME type, when I upload one using HTML/JS and check the type from the File object, it shows empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Correct .aab file MIME type is `application/x-authorware-bin`.

But do not rely on correct MIME info (property `type`) of JS object `<input type="file">`. Probably most suitable approach is to check file extension.